# LNK2019: Portability from Windows to OSX

Tags: windows, qt, visual-c++

I've been looking at this for the past couple of days with no success. I've been trying to create a graphics application with Qt. It seems like my LNK2019 should arise from from an unimplemented constructor:

```
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl            ArbObject::ArbObject(class Table *,int *,int,int,int,int,int)" (??
0ArbObject@@QEAA@PEAVTable@@PEAHHHHHH@Z) referenced in function "class std::vector<class ArbObject *,class std::allocator<class ArbObject *> > __cdecl 
createArbObjects(class QList<class QStringList> &,class Table *,int &)" (?createArbObjects@@YA?AV?$vector@PEAVArbObject@@V?$allocator@PEAVArbObject@@@std@@@std@@AEAV?   
$QList@VQStringList@@@@PEAVTable@@AEAH@Z)
```

However, the constructor is there and implemented in the appropriate .cpp file.

```
.h file has this:
 ArbObject(Table* tr, int* rgb, int t, int xpos, int ypos, int w, int h);

.cpp file has this:
ArbObject::ArbObject(Table* tr, int* rgb, int t, int xpos, int ypos, int w, int h)
    : QWidget((QWidget*)tr), obj_typ(t), xpos(xpos), ypos(ypos),wid(w), hei(h)
{
...
}
```

I've included everything I can think of. This doesn't work on my Windows machine, however it works perfectly well on my mac. My question is what sorts of dependencies could cause this sort of an issue? What other avenues can I explore to solve my problem?

- Is it compiler based? MSVC vs Clang
- Do both include different files in the linking process, hence it may not work on one platform as opposed to another.

---

EDIT: Fixed

See the answer!

Comment: Have you tried compiling your application with the MinGW compiler on Windows? What version of Qt are you using?

Comment: A constructor should always be __thiscall, not __cdecl.  Hard to see how you did that.

Comment: @HansPassant, here's my line in the function that the compiler is referring to 
ArbObject *a = new ArbObject(table, RGB, typ, xpos, ypos, width, height);
All the values here are ints except for table and RGB.

It's also saying File not found: main.obj. Perhaps it's using an old  version of the main.obj file, but rebuilding doesn't change this at all.

Comment: @Cameron Tinker, I've setup the MinGW compiler , added the build kit and set it default, and I get the same message. I'm using Qt 5.0.2

Answer (score -1):

It turns out that it was in fact the way that I structured my code that determined the compiler error. I don't know exactly why but it did but it's probably due to the way I structure my code.

Previously, I included a parser.h file with the relevant creation functions in my main.cpp file. My reasoning was the parser.h file will be included at the top of the main.cpp file. parser.h was essentially a place to keep the long functions out of sight.

Now, I create a separate class for parsing/creation, which has those methods to create arbobjects, balls and etc. The main function creates an instance of the parser and uses those methods. This makes it compile with no linker error